# Detect change in a Boolean value from True to False and Vice versa

Tags: python, flask

This is the flask based Web App.

```
@app.route('/receive', methods=['POST'])
def receive():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        powerOutage = data['powerOutage']

        # Send SMS here only once when the powerOutage value changes

        return '{"status":"OK"}'
```

The API function **receive** is called with HTTP POST from  Arduino based hardware.
I want to send an SMS when the value of the Boolean variable changes.
The hardware continuously send **True** when there is been power outage and **False** when there is no outage. I want to trigger an SMS gateway and send an SMS only once to the user whenever power outage just occur and when  it finishes and the device send the first **False** value. 
The Arduino based device sends the ***poweroutage*** every second.

what can I do to detect this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to send two params in `POST` request to receive function, one variable carrying the older value of power outage and one variable with the latest value. I believe this is required because you need to check the following conditions:

1. `old_pwr_outage != new_pwr_outage`
2. `new_pwr_outage == False`

Also, camel casing is not pythonic, you might want to change that. ;)

Comment: I try to be more Pythonic, Thanks for the tip. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple sollutions to read the value of a variable. Depending on your IDE you can debug your application and place a breakpoint after the variable. When using a more simple text editor printing out the value in the console would be usefull as well. You can print the value in the arduino console aswell as Python command line.

One more thing right know your function will return only something when the condition is met, you might want to retun a `400` status code(bad request) when the condition does not met your if-statement. This can cause null-pointer exceptions when the condition is `False`

So you could refactor your method like this:

```
@app.route('/receive', methods=['POST'])
def receive():
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.json
    powerOutage = data['powerOutage']

    # Send SMS here only once when the powerOutage value changes

    return '{"status":"OK"}'

 return '{"status":"BAD_REQUEST"}'
```

Comment: I want to initiate and SMS right from the web App , I don't want to send SMS on each request, I want  it only once when there is been transition between True to False and False to True. I have noting to do with  the Arduino and  when the Arduino receive **{'status':'OK'}** , that's enough to know the server received the data.